# Differences between utf8 and latin1

Tags: mysql, utf-8, installation, latin1

what is the difference between utf8 and latin1?

Comment: They are different encodings (with *some* characters mapped to common byte sequences, e.g. the ASCII characters and many accented letters). UTF-8 is one encoding of Unicode with all its codepoints; Latin1 encodes less than 256 characters.

Comment: There is also latin9 which is available in Linux locales and could have been mentioned in the question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048745/what-is-the-difference-between-utf-8-and-iso-8859-1)

Answer (score 186):

[UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is prepared for world domination, [Latin1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) isn't.

If you're trying to store non-Latin characters like Chinese, Japanese, Hebrew, Russian, etc using Latin1 encoding, then they will end up as [mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake). You may find the introductory text of [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html) useful (and even more if you know a bit Java).

Note that full 4-byte UTF-8 support was only introduced in MySQL 5.5. Before that version, it only goes up to 3 bytes per character, not 4 bytes per character. So, it supported only the BMP plane and not e.g. the Emoji plane. If you want full 4-byte UTF-8 support, upgrade MySQL to at least 5.5 or go for another RDBMS like PostgreSQL. In MySQL 5.5+ it's called [`utf8mb4`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html).

Comment: Mysql 5.1 supports 3 byte UTF-8, however Mysql 5.5 [does support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode.html) 4 byte UTF-8 as utf8mb4.

Comment: True that, but MySQL 5.5 wasn't GA at the moment this answer was posted. It was released December 2010.

Comment: @BalusC Can you elaborate more on how UTF-8 isn't fully supported? Does it mean that Mysql 5.1 can't store *all* unicode characters?

Comment: @Pacerier: it only supports 3 bytes per character, thus only the BMP (the first 65535 characters) is supported, the remnant not. For all characters, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)

Comment: @BalusC So how do we store the unicode character `LINEAR B SYLLABLE B008 A`? :  http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/10000/index.htm

Comment: @Pacerier: Upgrade to MySQL 5.5.

Comment: @BalusC As for people using 5.1.63 and don't have the privilege to update the web server's mysql version, what may be the alternatives?

Comment: @Pacerier: You could save as `VARBINARY` instead of `VARCHAR` and decode/encode in the business tier yourself, but this is hacky. Consider asking a new question, maybe there are better ways.

Comment: Good answer!  Sorry to nitpick.  Chinese, Japanese, Hebrew are languages and contain characters.  But Cyrillic is a language system (and contains languages).

Comment: @HoldOffHunger: Right, answer has been adjusted.

Comment: @Ali *"Before that version, it only goes up to 3 bytes, not 4 bytes per character."* And there's nothing specifically to "Mysql 5.1". The change was in MySQL 5.5.

Comment: You didn't answer the question, stackoverflow requires people to respond technically, not saying who is most used. Your answer is a typical offtopic.

Answer (score 63):

In latin1 each character is exactly one byte long. In utf8 a character can consist of more than one byte. Consequently utf8 has more characters than latin1 (and the characters they do have in common aren't necessarily represented by the same byte/bytesequence).

Comment: What about ascii and bin?

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub ASCII is a single-byte encoding which uses the characters 0 through 127, so it can encode half as many characters as latin1. It's a strict subset of both latin1 and utf8, meaning the bytes 0 through 127 in both latin1 and utf8 encode the same things as they do in ASCII. Bin isn't an encoding. It's usually an option that you can give when reading a file, telling the IO functions to not apply any encoding, but instead just read the file byte by byte.

Comment: thanks, I meant `binary` collate...? and which one is better for english/numeric fields: `ascii_general_ci` or `ascii_bin`?