# Difference In UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1

Tags: mysql, jsp, encoding

I have this &#2361 &#2379 and also this \u0936\u093e\u0902\u0924\u093f
But I dont know to what encoding they belong to.

The hindi font gets stored as the 1st encoding in the database.

So please tell me what type encoding it is?
And also how to get my hindi font characters in the 2nd encoding type(\u0924\u093f).

Comment: What do you mean by "what encoding they belong to"? These Unicode characters (\u0936\u093e\u0902\u0924\u093f, that is शांति) are not present in ISO-8859-1 if that's what you mean.

Comment: [What is the difference between UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7048745/1031945)

Answer (score 0):

Both `&#2361;` and `\u0939` encode the Unicode Character *Devanagari letter HA* : **ह**

`&#2361;` is the **HTML entity** that represents the unicode character 2361 in decimal, which is equivalent to hexadecimal 0939

`\u0939` is **javascript escape sequence** that represents the unicode character 0939 in hexadecimal, which is the equivalent to decimal 2361.

ISO 8859 do not include those characters.

Comment: One more thing is when i end this with semicolon  &#2361 &#2379 on stackoverflow I get the hindi charaters.But when I retrieve from database to pdf(xmlworker) I get the the same thing.

Comment: Ok thnx for the explaination..But stil I dont understand,when I create the pdf,\u0939 converts to hindi character but &#2381 gives the same thing back i.e &#2381(not a hindi character)

Comment: `&#2381;` is an HTML entity. It requires a browser or some other HTML interpreter to be rendered properly into the U+0939 unicode character. Probably the program you use to "create the pdf" does not process HTML entities.