# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 1

Tags: python, pandas, unicode, utf-8

I have got number of queries from the list, and I am executing them and saving them on excel file. Now each result will be store on each sheet of the excel file.
I am trying to run the queries in SQL Server, I was running the same code on Oracle and it was working, but its not working on SQL Server.

```
getting_list = self.create_list(connection_number)
query_sheet = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()+'/Docs/query_results.xlsx')
# writer = pd.ExcelWriter(query_sheet)
for q in self.queries:
    df = pd.read_sql_query(q, self.conn)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(query_sheet, engine='xlsxwriter')
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name=str(self.queries.index(q) + 1))
    writer.save()
```

On running I am having this exception

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 1: invalid start byte
```

and this exception is appearing on following line.

```
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name=str(self.queries.index(q) + 1))
```

Please Tell me where I am making mistake.

Comment: try to add encoding in the argument of your function : I would suggest encoding='iso8859-1' for example.. What language is used in your data?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get that.How can I achieve that?

Comment: `xlsx` is a zip package containing XML files. It doesn't have encodings. Supposing `query_results.xlsx` is a real `xlsx` file and not eg a `csv` or `html` file with a fake extension, what does the dataframe contain?

Comment: SQL query results.

Comment: @taimoorpasha obviously. What data does it contain? Text, numbers? If text, is it Unicode or encoded? Does it come from a non-Unicode database field? If so, the code will choke when it finds the first non-ANSI byte.

Comment: It contains multiple data, like phone numbers, text, intergers, even data in encrypted form as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 0: invalid start byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23772144/python-unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xc0-in-position-0-i)