# problem importing csv file to pycharm using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, import

I am trying to import file to PyCharm using pandas here is my code:

```
 import pandas as pd
 data=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\agns1\Downloads\data_work_final.csv')
```

sadly I'm getting this error:

```
 File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 542, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
 File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 642, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._get_header
 File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 843, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
 File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1917, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
 UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 4: invalid continuation 
 byte
```

any thoughts on how can I fix this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 0: invalid start byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23772144/python-unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xc0-in-position-0-i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the file encoding:

```
with open(r'C:\Users\agns1\Downloads\data_work_final.csv', 'rb') as rawdata:
    result = chardet.detect(rawdata.read(10000))


print(result)
```

You'll get something like:

```
{'encoding': <'the actual encoding'>, 'confidence': xxx, 'language': xxxx}
```

Then do:

```
data=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\agns1\Downloads\data_work_final.csv', encoding='<'the actual encoding'>')
```