# How to convert [u8] of Unicode code points to str in Rust?

Tags: string, rust

I have a `u8` slice that I would like to convert into a string, treating each `u8` as the literal Unicode code point (that is, U+0000 to U+00FF).

The closest I've found is [from_utf8](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/fn.from_utf8.html) which would interpret the slice as UTF8, but I'm not after UTF8, but the literal code points instead.

How to do this?

Comment: Rust's [`char`s](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html) are [Unicode scalar values](http://www.unicode.org/glossary/#unicode_scalar_value); if that's good enough, you can just cast each byte to `char`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the options to convert ISO-8859-1 / Latin-1 to a String (UTF-8)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28169745/what-are-the-options-to-convert-iso-8859-1-latin-1-to-a-string-utf-8)

Comment: Sounds like you're asking for exactly a decoding of Latin-1 encoded text to a `String`.

Answer (score 3):

```
fn main() {
    let codepoint_array: Vec<u8> = "test".into();
    let codepoints: Vec<char> = codepoint_array.into_iter().map(char::from).collect();
    println!("{:?}", codepoints);
}
```

(I have no idea why you'd want to do this, since that would give you a the Latin-1 supplement and the Latin Extended A, but nothing else...)

Comment: Oh, it's simple. The data I'm receiving is defined exactly like this.

Comment: You can also [collect into `String`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a2bfc4c1ce64658d0fec5382fa114960&version=stable).