# Character encoding issues PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

Could someone help me on how to fix this bad encoding?

The right output would be Église (this is what I have in the DB), however I'm getting Ã‰glise in the html output.

After running mb_detect_encoding(), I get "UTF-8". I've tried utf8_decode() without success, so I'm kind of lost and would need some guidance. Thanks all!

Comment: Content type of the html is set to UTF-8?

Comment: Yes. The data comes from a mssql database (ISO-8859-1) - legacy application

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048745/what-is-the-difference-between-utf-8-and-iso-8859-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost definitely an issue with the charset. If you're using Apache you can [force charset utf-8](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/force-charset-utf-8/) in your .htaccess:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Alternatively, you can also set the charset in PHP

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

Note that [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) must come before any output.

Comment: Adding charset=UTF-8 to the header did fix. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a meta tag with the charset attribute in your HTML document to encode your web page. Add the following meta tag in your head section.

```
<meta charset='utf-8'>
```

Hope it should work.

Comment: It's set already, I forgot to mention it's an ajax call and the results will be displayed in a new drop down. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You mean the data from ajax response will be populated in a drop down control and the encoding in it doesn't work?

Comment: exactly. It's weird.

Comment: If you're using jQuery for ajax operation, you need to specify contentType property in $.ajax like $.ajax({url: 'page.php', contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'});