# PHP function mb_detect_encoding strict mode

Tags: php, character-encoding

In the function [mb_detect_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) there is a parameter for strict mode.

In the first, most upvoted comment:

```
<?php
$str = 'áéóú'; // ISO-8859-1
mb_detect_encoding($str, 'UTF-8'); // 'UTF-8'
mb_detect_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', true); // false
```

This is true, yes. But can anybody give me an explanation, why is it?

Comment: Ultimately that flag gets passed through to [here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/c72282a13b12b7e572469eba7a7ce593d900a8a2/ext/mbstring/libmbfl/mbfl/mbfilter.c#L718); but I be damned if I can figure out what it does…

Comment: FWIW, *yet another* reason not to never use this function, because *detecting* encodings is fundamentally impossible to begin with. Very interesting question nonetheless.

Comment: @deceze Funny: the only comment about `strict` in the entire source code is `/* set strict flag */`

Comment: @Álvaro Yup, super helpful. *Thanks, guys…* ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything in this answer is based on my reading of the code [here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/c72282a13b12b7e572469eba7a7ce593d900a8a2/ext/mbstring/libmbfl/mbfl/mbfilter.c#L718) and [here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/c72282a13b12b7e572469eba7a7ce593d900a8a2/ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_utf8.c#L243).

I did not write it, I did not step through it with a debugger, this is my interpretation only.

---

It seems that the *intention* was for strict mode to check if the string as a whole was valid for the encoding, while non-strict mode would allow for a sub-sequence that *could be part of a valid string.* For example, if the string ended with what should be the first byte of a multi-byte character it would not match in strict mode but would still qualify as UTF-8 under non-strict mode.

However there seems to be a bug* where in non-strict mode only the first byte of the string is being checked in some circumstances.

**Example:**

The byte `0xf8` is not allowed anywhere in UTF-8. When placed at the start of a string `mb_detect_encoding()` properly returns false for it regardless of which mode is used.

```
$str = "\xf8foo";

var_dump(
    mb_detect_encoding($str, 'UTF-8'),      // bool(false)
    mb_detect_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', true) // bool(false)
);
```

But as long as the leading byte may occur anywhere in a UTF-8 sequence, non-strict mode returns UTF-8.

```
$str = "foo\xf8";

var_dump(
    mb_detect_encoding($str, 'UTF-8'),      // string(5) "UTF-8"
    mb_detect_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', true) // bool(false)
);
```

---

So while your ISO-8859-1 string `'áéóú'` is not valid UTF-8, the first byte `"\xe1"` can occur in UTF-8 and `mb_detect_encoding()` mistakenly returns the string as such.

---

*<sub>I've opened a report for this at https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72933</sub>

Answer (score 2):

`áéóú` in ISO-8859-1 encodes as:

```
e1 e9 f3 fa
```

If you mis-interpret it as UTF-8 you only get four invalid byte sequences. The Multi-Byte extension is basically designed to ignore errors. For instance, `mb_convert_encoding()` will replace those sequences with [question marks](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/003f/index.htm) or whatever you set with `mb_substitute_character()`.

My educated guess is that strict encoding determines what should be done with invalid byte sequences:

- `false` means to remove them
- `true` means to keep them

If you ignore these invalid sequences you're obviously discarding extremely valuable information and you only get sensible results in very limited circumstances, e.g.

```
$str = chr(81);
var_dump( mb_detect_encoding($str, ['ISO-8859-1', 'Windows-1252']) );
var_dump( mb_detect_encoding($str, ['Windows-1252', 'ISO-8859-1']) );
```

To sum up, `mb_detect_encoding()` is in general not as useful as you may thing and it's total crap with the default parameters.

Comment: Whether to laugh or to cry, that is the question.

Answer (score -2):

Because `$str` is not actual `UTF-8`, but `ISO-8859-1`. Since when not strict comparison, `UTF-8` may be treated same as `ISO-8859-1`, but when using strict mode only actual `UTF-8` fits for `UTF-8` comparison ([explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048745/what-is-the-difference-between-utf-8-and-iso-8859-1))

Comment: Those specific characters look very differently in UTF-8 and 8859. They're most certainly *not* the same and cannot be "treated the same". This is only true for the first 128 characters (ASCII), which these do not fall into. That string is plain invalid in UTF-8, period.