# JSON which is formatted as string, convert to php array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I have a JSON string which is stored in a MYSQL DB. Example:

```
stdClass Object (
[product] => stdClass Object
    (
        [sold_individually] => 
        [regular_price] => 
        [managing_stock] => 1
        [sku] => 0001
        [title] => Sample title
        [reviews_allowed] => 1...
```

etc.

I have used utf8_encode() to convert it. How can I then turn this in to a PHP array so I can use it?

**Edit 1**

I have now used json_encode() when posting to the DB. I have also had to use addSlashes() as I was getting some formatting issues with some of the values.

When I now pull in the data it looks like:

```
"{\"product\": {\"sold_individually\": false, \"regular_price\": \"\", \"managing_stock\": true, \"sku\": \"W-C-6500\", \"title\": \"Sample title\"...
```

How can I pull out the value for "title"? Should I also use str_replace() to get rid of the \ issue?

Comment: have you tried PHP's "json_decode" function?

Comment: did you try $array =  json_decode($json,1); ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried using json_decode() and I get NULL back. Do I need to turn the string in to an object?

Answer (score 1):

What you printed is not JSON, it's the string representation of a php Object I think. So if possible, you should store into your database actual JSON. It's easier, cleaner and more compact.

To do so, use json_encode($your_object) to insert the data in your database.

To retrieve it, use json_decode($string_from_database).

This should work like a charm.

**Note:**
There's a trap though, by default, json_decode will create a php Object and not an array. So you have to retrieve your fields as attributes of an object:

```
$data = json_decode($string_from_database);
$data->product->title; // to access title in your data structure
```

But if you want an array, you can provide an argument to get an array and then it works like this:

```
$data = json_decode($string_from_database, true);
$data['product']['title']; // to access title in your data structure
```

Check the php documentation of json_decode for further info!

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Thank you this has really helped. I realised I has set json_decode before posting it which was the issue. I am now able to use json_encode when posting it and json_decode to retrieve it. 
How do I get access to a particular field though? ie: title

Comment: Oh yeah, there's a trap, by default, json_decode will create a php Object and not an array. So you have to retrieve your fields as attributes of an object:
    $data = json_decode($string_from_database);
    $data->product->title; // to access title in your data structure

Comment: But if you want an array, you can provide an argument to get an array like this: json_decode($string_from_database, true) and in that case, you can access the data like this: $data['product']['title'] Ceck the php documentation of json_decode for further info!

Comment: Thanks Louis. I realised yesterday we had posted it as a string and not pure JSON. I managed to use what you have posted above and it now works like a treat ;) thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a utility called [utf8_decode(string)](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_xml_utf8_decode.asp) which converts previously encoded with the utf8_encode() function, back to [ISO-8859-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048745/what-is-the-difference-between-utf-8-and-iso-8859-1). From there you have utility available to make a string a array/Json,etc.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I was posting the JSON as a string and not pure JSON which prevented me from using json_decode when it came back out.