# File name downloaded containing special characters is different than in the server

Tags: java, character-encoding, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to download a file from an URL, but when my file is saved the name is different than it should be when it contains special characters. Here is the code I'm using

```
URL url = new URL(fileURL);

    HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    int responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();

    // always check HTTP response code first
    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        String fileName = "";
        String disposition = httpConn.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition");
        String contentType = httpConn.getContentType();
        int contentLength = httpConn.getContentLength();

        if (disposition != null) {
            // extracts file name from header field
            int index = disposition.indexOf("filename=");
            if (index > 0) {
                fileName =  disposition.substring(index + 10,
                        disposition.length() - 1);
            }
        } else {
            // extracts file name from URL
            fileName = fileURL.substring(fileURL.lastIndexOf("/") + 1,
                    fileURL.length());
        }

        System.out.println("Content-Type = " + contentType);
        System.out.println("Content-Disposition = " + disposition);
        System.out.println("Content-Length = " + contentLength);



        // opens input stream from the HTTP connection
        InputStream inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
        String saveFilePath = saveDir + File.separator + fileName;

        // opens an output stream to save into file
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(saveFilePath);

        int bytesRead = -1;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();

        System.out.println("Fichier téléchargé");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Pas de fichier trouvé à l'URL: " + fileURL + ". 
 HTTP code retourné par le serveur: " + responseCode);
    }
    httpConn.disconnect();
}
```

This is the name in the server "&éù%$£µ#çàè.png" and this is the name I get after download "&Ã©Ã¹%$Â£Âµ#Ã§Ã Ã¨.png"

What I'am getting wrong?
PS: here is an example of the output of my code

```
Répertoire de sauvegarde: C:\Data\downloads
Content-Type = image/png
Content-Disposition = attachment; filename="&Ã©Ã¹%$Â£Âµ#Ã§Ã Ã¨.png"
Content-Length = 2208482
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What server are you using? You were using ISO-8859-1 ([checked here](http://www.webatic.com/run/chars/charset_decoder.php)) [Can you switch to UTF-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7048774/4906586)

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
It is resolved by always ensuring that the saved fileName is UTF-8 encoding:
    `fileName = new String(fileName.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");`

Comment: Glad to see this. I was asking about the server because I'm working under GlassFish and you can configure the default encoding in glassfish-web.xml. This is one solution, you have other solutions such as Filter.