# PHP - Strlen behaves very strange, the same things - different results, lol numbers?

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, utf-8, strlen

[image]

`tresc` and `tresc_pelna`

The same type, the same content

[image]

`The same content`. `876` characters in total.

Taken from db by `...AS data_dodania, p.data_modyfikacji, p.tresc, p.tresc_pelna, p.url, count(k.id)...`

Echeon to website by `<?= strlen($post['tresc_pelna']).'----'.strlen($post['tresc']) ?>`

And guess what?

This is the output

`876----3248`

What the...?

I have completly no Idea what is happening here xD.

Please help guys :D

Both fields `utf8_polish_ci` and exactly same content

`<?= mb_strlen($post['tresc_pelna'], 'utf-8').'----'.mb_strlen($post['tresc'], 'utf-8') ?>`

Still bad result.

`tresc` over 3 thousands... what the... How? why?

Comment: Whats the collation of those fields?

Comment: @tkausl both are `utf8_polish_ci` And both have exactly the same content

Comment: And the character sets aren't changed manually? I.e., they are both `utf8`?

Comment: @tkausl all time utf-8

Comment: And when you echo both of em, same exact output?

Comment: Don't copy/paste data in and out of mySQL, especially that god-awful disaster that is phpMyAdmin. You're likely ruining the character encoding. You should also [read up on what UTF8 actually is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048745/what-is-the-difference-between-utf-8-and-iso-8859-1/39109074#39109074).

Comment: mb_strlen might be your friend here.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has two built-in functions for determining the length of variable-length items. One, which counts distinct unicode characters, [is called `CHAR_LENGTH()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length). The other counts octets (bytes), and is [called `LENGTH()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_length).

In PHP, `strlen()` counts octets, like MySQL's `LENGTH()`.  Many unicode strings, especially those encoded in utf8, have a variable number of octets per character. You can [use grapheme_strlen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.grapheme-strlen.php) to count those.

I've found it's sometimes helpful to do `SELECT HEX(unicode_column)` to figure out what's stashed in MySQL. Just fetching the column data puts you at the mercy of the character rendering of the MySQL client you use, and can be very confusing.

It's also possible your database columns have entitized data in them (for example the string `&eacute;` rather than the Unicode character `é`. If that entity text gets sent to a web browser, it renders as the letter.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `LENGTH` and `CHAR_LENGTH` could explain a ratio of under 1.2x for most European text.  It won't explain 3248:876, which is nearly 4x.

Perhaps these are part of the answer:

- Htmlentities, such as `&oacute;` which is taking 8 bytes to represent a 2-byte utf8 character.  We can't see whether one of them has `<` and the other has `&lt;`.
- Formatting tags, such as `<p>`.  Again, possibly `&lt;p&gt;`

Still, that is not enough to explain nearly 4x.  For example, a simple letter, such  as `a`, will be one byte, regardless of how it is encoded.  Please provide the HEX for a *small* sample.