# Limit Google Cloud Vision's Character set

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I didn't see anything in the [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/python/vision/latest/gapic/v1/api.html#google.cloud.vision_v1.ImageAnnotatorClient.document_text_detection) about being able to instruct the OCR parser to return only `Latin-1` characters (which encodes [just the first 256 code points of the Unicode character set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7048780/3491991)). For example, the OCR interpreted a `"` double quotation mark as `”` which looks an awful lot like a double quotation mark but is `unicode` character `\u201d`.

Limiting the charset could be a good way to improve OCRing (assuming a document is expected to be in a certain language) and make downstream text processing more predictable. Is this possible?

Comment: You could try language_hints if you know the language: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.vision.v1#imagecontext