# @RequestMapping handling of special characters

Tags: java, spring, rest, media-type

I have a REST API

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Save", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
            consumes = {"application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1" }, 
            produces = {"application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1" })    
public SaveResponse save(@RequestBody SaveRequest request) {
        //some codes
    }
}
```

My request contains the following lines

```
{
  :
  :
      "mailingAddress": {
      "addressLine1": "Carrera 36E N°",
      "addressLine2": "Medellín, Antioquia",
      "country": "COL"
    }
  :
```

And I received a 400 Bad Request

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Date: Wed, 16 Jun 2021 12:26:37 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 0
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-RBT-Optimized-By: CANA014IJT (RiOS 6.1.1a #11) SC
```

And when I removed the characters "°" and "í" from the request, then the request can go through with no error. What is my problem?

Thank you.

Comment: If the API is yours, simply change the charset in "application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1" from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8.

Comment: Is there a reason you’re using ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8?

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the character set from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8, as the former does not support as wide an array of character mappings ([What is the difference between UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048745/what-is-the-difference-between-utf-8-and-iso-8859-1)).