# What is the Ideal Encoding Setting for Database Supporting Multi-language?

Tags: mysql, performance, encoding

According to MySQL [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset.html), MySQL includes character set support that enables us to store data using a variety of character sets and perform comparisons according to a variety of collations. **Character sets can be specified at four different levels**:

- Server
- Database
- Table
- Column

Assuming I have a database that stores the following:

- User ID (INT)
- Email Address (VARCHAR 50)
- User profile (TEXT - multi-language)
- System flag (CHAR 1 - a-z only)

Between `Latin1` and `UTF-8`, which should I choose for the **four different levels** to achieve the best possible performance?

**ADD NOTE:** This is just a simplified example. In real scenario, I would expect several columns storing (a-zA-Z0-9) and one or two columns storing multi-lingual text. That is why I am concerned about performance.

**ADD NOTE2:** I am referring to a database that stores millions of records. That is why performance matters to me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708958/differences-between-utf8-and-latin1

Comment: @ yytg, I know the difference between UTF-8 and Latin1. Now I am asking how to apply it at the four levels.

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367711/what-is-the-best-collation-to-use-for-mysql-with-php

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong, but from my experience the character set of your choice doesn't really have a big impact on your overall database performance (if you start mixing them up in different tables, now *that* might affect query performance).

If you want to support multiple languages, go for `utf8` (or even `utf16`).

Comment: UTF-8 is one to three bytes. It does have performance impact on memory. I am not sure about query speed.

Comment: Everything has some kind of impact, but in most situations the difference `latin1` to `uft8` is just too insignificant.

Answer (score 0):

You should choose the same encoding for the whole database. Otherwise you as a developer will be confused later. And since the text is multilingual, is only leaves `utf8` as the encoding of your choice.

Note that you can choose an encoding for the *database connection*, too.

Comment: Yes, I think server refers to database connection or instance, and database refers to schema on the manual. I am not sure about the performance impact since there will be millions of rows to deal with.