# MySQL InooDB error [42000][1118] Row size too large (> 8126) main solution did not work

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm having this problem which appeared suddenly without updating local server at all any it was working fine. I tried to update data in a text field of MySQL 5.6 InnoDB but i got this error (table contains 24 text fields with only 1 row)

```
[42000][1118] Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB or using 
ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC or ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix 
of 768 bytes is stored inline.
```

So I searched and found this solution (change in my.ini) and restarted MySQL service [Solution page](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90096/row-size-too-large-8126)

```
max_allowed_packet = 1G
innodb_log_file_size = 2G
innodb_log_buffer_size = 512M
```

But it didn't solve the problem then searched again and found this solution here in stackoverflow [Solution page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163614/error-1118-42000-row-size-too-large) and restarted MySQL service

```
innodb_log_file_size = 10G
```

and tried to use compression like this

```
ALTER TABLE pages ROW_FORMAT=compressed
```

but got this warning

```
Warning Code : 1478
InnoDB: ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED requires innodb_file_format > Antelope.
Warning Code : 1478
InnoDB: assuming ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT.
```

And it didn't solve the problem too. So how to solve this problem on localhost and on the server without restarting the MySQL service because the hosting would refuse restarting.

Comment: Did you try *Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB or using 
ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC or ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED*

Comment: Yes using this ALTER TABLE table_name ROW_FORMAT=compressed

Comment: But got this warning Warning Code : 1478
InnoDB: ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED requires innodb_file_format > Antelope.

Warning Code : 1478
InnoDB: assuming ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT.

Comment: Without restarting the service, the changes in `my.ini` will not be effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plan A (work around): Build a parallel table ("Vertical partitioning").  Move some of the big fields to it.  The new table can have the same `PRIMARY KEY` (but not `AUTO_INCREMENT`).  Use `JOIN` when you need to `SELECT` both sets of columns.

Plan B:  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can critique the columns.

Comment: dividing columns worked fine but I had only 1 row with 24 text columns

Comment: Almost sounds like 24 rows of one text each might be convenient enough.