# Database is not importing giving following error

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to import a database file on local server using wamp . I am getting following error. How this can be resolved, Thank you for all your help

SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_bwg_theme` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `thumb_margin` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `thumb_padding` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `thumb_border_radius` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `thumb_border_width` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `thumb_border_style` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `thumb_border_color` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `thumb_bg_color` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `thumbs_bg_color` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `thumb_bg_transparent` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `thumb_box_shadow` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `thumb_transparent` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `thumb_align` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `thumb_hover_effect` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `thumb_hover_effect_value` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `thumb_transition` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `thumb_title_font_color` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `thumb_title_font_style` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `thumb_title_pos` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `thumb_title_font_size` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `thumb_title_font_weight` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `thumb_title_margin` varchar(32) NOT N[...]
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> 1118 - Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 0 bytes is stored inline.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR 1118 (42000) Row size too large](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163614/error-1118-42000-row-size-too-large)