# How to fix "ERROR 1118 (42000): Row size too large (> 8126)" with MariaDB 5.5?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, innodb

I am uploading a CSV file with 314 columns to a MariaDB 5.5 server. Currently my code looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
   (column_1 TEXT,
    column_2 TEXT,
    ...
    column_314 TEXT)
ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE filepath  
INTO TABLE table_name 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

This results in the following error:

```
ERROR 1118 (42000): Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB
may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 0 bytes is stored inline.
```

I am using the Barracuda InnoDB file format with file per table enabled:

```
innodb_file_format=Barracuda
innodb_file_per_table=1
```

I believe the problem is the innodb page size, which is set to 16k. Since I am on MariaDB 5.5 and not 10.1+ I don't believe there is a way to increase the page size either. The database is managed by an organization and cannot currently be upgraded to a newer version.

Comment: Because MariaDB and MySQL both use the same database structure in this case (innoDB), the answers for MySQL are also almost certainly the same methods for MariaDB. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163614/error-1118-42000-row-size-too-large)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR 1118 (42000) Row size too large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163614/error-1118-42000-row-size-too-large)

Comment: please share confirmation that you've read and tried these solutions and state If the answers (t)here do **not** answer your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

314 columns is "too many".  But, since it is rather messy to split it up the CSV file, here are some thoughts on what *might* help you get it loaded with that many columns:

- Be sure to use minimal-sized integers:  `TINYINT UNSIGNED` is only 1 byte and allows numbers 0..255.  See the manual for other sizes.
- Be sure to use minimal-sized `VARCHARs`:  Don't simply say `VARCHAR(255)` for everything.  If you under-shoot, you will get truncation, so it may take a couple of passes to figure out the best sizes.
- Use `CHARACTER SET latin1` for any columns that you know to be just English, or even Western European.  Else use `utf8` or `utf8mb4` where necessary.
- Avoid `TEXT` and `BLOB` unless necessary.

Show us a sample of the data; we may have further tips.

(You *could* raise the 16KB limit to 64KB, but that would change the limit for all table, forever.  Hardly anyone does such.  I don't know the perils, if any.)