# How to set row_format during sql import using phpMyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm actually trying to make a copy of my web-site and hence exported an Sql file from my web-server. In my local machine, I created a new database using phpMyadmin. When I import the Sql file into my database, I get this error:

MySQL said:
 #1118 - Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB or using ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC or ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 768 bytes is stored inline.

I see others have hit this error and information on how to alter table using ALTER_TABLE command or change some setting in my.cnf or my.ini. I do not want to go in and edit the sql file to add row_format to 1000's of create table commands. Is there a simpler way to over come this error before importing the Sql file by using phpMyadmin interface.

Comment: The error-message hints that the error is in your data, not your config. Do you have a lot of ENUM-Cols in your data?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13283381/row-size-too-large-error-in-mysql-create-table-query