# Table storage engine for <TABLE> doesn't have this option on order by query (ERROR 1031)

Tags: mysql, sql

> Table storage engine for <TABLE> doesn't have this option.

This is the error returned by MySQL on an `order by` query. The column type is `varchar(2000)`.

Query:

```
select * from `dbo.table_1` order by textT;
```

Error returned:

> ERROR 1031 (HY000): Table storage engine for 'dbo.table_1' doesn't have this option.

Why does this happen? And how can I fix it?

Comment: use separate backticks for both database name `dbo` and table name `table_1`

Comment: statement should look like `select * from \`dbo\`.\`table_1\` order by textT`

Comment: May be an issue of `max_length_for_sort_data`

Comment: Check this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-storage-engine.html

Comment: @Ravinder I used backticks but error return consistantly.

Comment: Please edit and add result of `show create table dbo.table_1` to your posting

Comment: @UmairIqbal: And also look into the storage engine page referred by `Stanislovas Kalašnikovas`

Comment: You have left out three important bits of info, and none of the commenters have asked for them. -- What Version of MySQL?  Which Storage ENGINE?  Provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_1`.

Comment: I got this error when trying to load a 5.5 dump using a 5.5 server, in case it might help someone.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

This problem appears to occur when you're importing a table definition that had been created with MyISAM but later was switched to InnoDB; the resulting `ROW_FORMAT` options appear to be invalid.

If you're trying to import an exported database and encounter this problem, you can simply search and replace `ROW_FORMAT=FIXED` with nothing.

I used the following to do so really quickly:

```
sed -ie 's/ROW_FORMAT=FIXED//g' backup.sql
```

Problem solved! Thanks to jbrahy for pointing out that it was the ROW_FORMAT that was the problem.

EDIT: Updated to work for more platforms as per @seven's suggestion

EDIT2: Also note, as per @Steen-Schütt, this may be a safer fix

```
sed -ie 's/ROW_FORMAT=FIXED/ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT/g' backup.sql
```

Comment: This worked for me, I was blocked from importing from a dump file, and now it imports.

Comment: nice quickie! saved me

Comment: @haagsma suggesting edit for "-ie" instead of just sed -e. -ie works both on GNU and BSD versions of sed. I am os osx and -i works differently) ```sed -ie 's/ROW_FORMAT=FIXED//g' backup.sql```

Comment: If @jbrahy pointed out the problem, shouldn't he be awarded the answer? Seems weird that he has 4 points and you have 32 when his was the correct answer.

Comment: I think this error is mostly thrown when importing a backup; and as this is the quickest way to fix the issue in that case...
I can edit my answer to include some more details of the problem though.

Comment: @SivaKaruppiah details?

Comment: I'm getting "Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. This includes storage overhead" error

Comment: That looks like it's related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13283381/row-size-too-large-error-in-mysql-create-table-query
You are have an additional problem related to conversion. Try replacing longer varchars with text in that case.

Comment: According to [this bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=77625), `FIXED` is silently changed to `COMPACT` in MySQL 5.6 and before. That seems to suggest that `sed -ie 's/ROW_FORMAT=FIXED/ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT/g' backup.sql` would be a "safer" solution in terms of maintaining the same behaviour.

Answer (score 13):

You can also try this:

```
ALTER TABLE `dbo.table_1` ROW_FORMAT = DEFAULT ;
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly for me and saved me having to rebuild innodb multiple tables full of foreign keys.

Answer (score 11):

I get the same error when I import a table definition that's InnoDB with ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC in it. The table was created with a MyISAM engine but I later switched it to InnoDB. When I removed the ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC from the create table statement and recreated the table it worked fine. My solution to your problem would be this.

```
show create table `dbo.table_1`;
```

then take the output from that command and remove the ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC then rename the table to `dbo.table_1_old`

```
rename table `dbo.table_1` to `dbo.table_1_old`;
```

Then execute the create table statement from the first step i.e.

```
-- don't use this create as there are missing columns use yours
create table `dbo.table_1` (textT VARCHAR(255));
```

Then repopulate your table with the old data.

```
insert into `dbo.table_1` select * from `dbo.table_1_old`;
```

Then you should be able to execute your original SQL

```
select * from `dbo.table_1` order by textT;
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem appears to occur when you're importing a table definition to MySQL 5.7 that had been created with MySQL 5.6 and earlier. The same error can produceb by option KEY_BUFFER_SIZE=8192 and similar sizes defined in bytes for INNODB ENGINE. 
I had this error when I'm importing base from sql-dump.
Decision: sed -ie 's/KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=16384//g' my-file-sql_dump.sql

Answer (score 2):

I was facing this problem and my backup file was encrypted `.zsql` file. So I modified my.cnf by adding `innodb_strict_mode = off`. It worked fine