# case sensitive LIKE on VARCHAR field with cp1251 encoding

Tags: mysql, sql, case-sensitive, cp1251

I have an InnoDB table with VARCHAR(250) cp1251_general_ci field named `comment`.

I'm trying to search on this field, case sentative.

```
SELECT comment
FROM body_legend
WHERE comment LIKE '%ТТ%'
GROUP BY comment
```

works as expected, but its case insensitive.

I tried to use `BINARY` like

```
SELECT comment
FROM body_legend 
WHERE comment LIKE BINARY '%ТТ%'
GROUP BY comment`
```

it returns an empty result.

I tried to use `COLLATE` like

```
SELECT comment
FROM body_legend
WHERE comment LIKE '%ТТ%' COLLATE cp1251_general_ci
```

it returns error

```
 COLLATION 'cp1251_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4'
```

How to make search case sensitive? I would be glad if the answer is complemented by a description of why did not work my queries.

Comment: `WHERE BINARY comment LIKE '%ТТ%'`

Comment: @Mihai SELECT comment FROM body_legend WHERE BINARY comment LIKE '%ТТ%' return an empty result

Comment: How about `WHERE comment COLLATE latin1_general_cs LIKE '%ТТ%'` Assuming you have TT somewhere in there

Comment: @Mihai #1253 - COLLATION 'latin1_general_cs' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'cp1251'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16561447/why-cant-i-use-a-specific-collation-in-mysql http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629111/how-can-i-make-sql-case-sensitive-string-comparison-on-mysql

Comment: Read both topics but its not help me. Tried all combinations of COLLATE. Is it possible to conver '%TT%' to cp1251_general_ci?

Answer (score 0):

Self-answer:

```
SELECT comment
FROM body_legend
WHERE comment
LIKE BINARY CONVERT( '%ТТ%' USING cp1251);
```

It seems that if I write this query in the phpMyAdmin it is read as the utf8 and in bit-wise comparison with the value in the cp1251 table, of course, is not the same.