# CryptoJS with hex key not decrypting properly

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptojs

I have a dataset that was encrypted that I'm trying to decrypt with CryptoJS.  I've tried various combination of things but for some reason the result is not what I'm expecting.  I have provided the key below and also the text I want to decrypt.  What I'm expecting at msg1 is 32 characters long but I keep getting 48.  Its as of its padding it with an extra 16 characters.

Thanks in advance for the help.

```
key = 'd13484fc2f28fd0426ffd201bbd2fe6ac213542d28a7ca421f17adc0cf234381';
text = '8bf3955488af91feb7bd87220910cee0';


decrypt(text: string): void{

       let msg1 = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(text, CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(key), { mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB, padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding});
       msg1 = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(msg1 );

}
```

Comment: It is adding 16 characters of padding because the text is exactly a block multiple, the text `"Test data from windows - mary had a little lamb "` has a trailing space character so padding adds a full block of padding. Do not specify `CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding` on decryption, specify CBC padding. But there seems to be some mixing of the original question and this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving it is pretty simple, but reading the docs and the code, I'm not quite clear why.

This is clearly wrong:

```
let msg1 = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(text, CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(key), { mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB, padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding});
```

Given your description, you are expecting the byte sequence represented by the hex digits "8bf3955488af91feb7bd87220910cee0" to be the body. But that's not what your passing. You're passing the *characters*. So when it decrypts it, the first byte is the ASCII value of `8` (0x38), not 0x8b. Given that, you should be parsing the hex like this:

```
let msg1 = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(text), ...
```

But, for reasons I'm having trouble understanding, that doesn't work. `decrypt` expects Base64 (or at least it will accept Base64). I can't find any documentation that says this, and the code creates the `decrypt` function magically in a way that I don't fully understand, and this is why I really hate doing crypto work in JavaScript.

That's out of my system now, so let's get to the answer:

```
cipher = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(text))

let msg1 = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(cipher, CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(key), { mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB, padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding});
```

And that should give you the result you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks that was it.

Answer (score 0):

Given:
`key = 'd13484fc2f28fd0426ffd201bbd2fe6ac213542d28a7ca421f17adc0cf234381';`
`text = '8bf3955488af91feb7bd87220910cee0';`.

Decrypting the text with the key actually produces: `C5640000B550000079320000217C0000`.

See [AES Calc](http://extranet.cryptomathic.com/aescalc?key=d13484fc2f28fd0426ffd201bbd2fe6ac213542d28a7ca421f17adc0cf234381&iv=00000000000000000000000000000000&input=8bf3955488af91feb7bd87220910cee0&mode=ecb&action=Decrypt&output=)

Verify the encoding that `CryptoJS.AES.decrypt` requires for it's inputs and output encoding.

Comment: Yes I understand that that should be the right answer but when using CryptoJS I'm getting '71dbf42d47bc84f19e7124393b35d36634aca7fb7f0ba46d'