# Incorrect decrypted string implemented using AES/ECB/NoPadding and base 64 with crypto-js library

Tags: javascript, aes, cryptojs, ecb

I am trying to encrypt/decrypt the below data using crypto-js and getting unexpected results.

Library: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js

```
function encryptByAESECB(message, key) {
    var keyHex = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key);
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(message, keyHex, {
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding
    });
    return encrypted.toString();
}
function decryptByAESECB(ciphertext, key) {
    var keyHex = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key);

    // direct decrypt ciphertext
    var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt({
        ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(ciphertext)
    }, keyHex, {
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding
    });

    return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
}

var message = 'Message';
var key = '5401cae4-2c89-49';

var ciphertext = encryptByAESECB(message, key);
// ciphertext: 8dKft9vkZ4I=
console.info('ciphertext:', ciphertext);
var plaintext = decryptByAESECB(ciphertext, key);
// plaintext : Message
console.info('plaintext :', plaintext);
```

Expected output: `"Message"`

Current output: Error Message "Malformed UTF-8 data"

Code debug link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/aes-ecb-bhardwaj

`NOTE: If I am using other paddings like Pkcs7 and ZeroPadding it seems to be working fine.`

Comment: _Expected output: "Message"_ - actually CryptoJS should handle this as an error (e.g. with an exception), because a block cipher (like AES-ECB) with disabled padding (`CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding`) can only encrypt plaintext whose length is an integer multiple of the blocksize (16 bytes for AES), which is not the case here (`Message` is only 7 bytes large).

Comment: @Topaco This seems to be the reason, I tried with ZeroPadding and it seemed to be working fine then.
Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, a plaintext whose length is not an integer multiple of the blocksize cannot be encrypted with AES-ECB if padding is disabled. Therefore, (at least) one of these conditions must be changed implicitly so that encryption is possible at all.

*CryptoJS* uses the [`WordArray`](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/blob/develop/src/core.js) data type that encapsulates a word array (`words`) and the number of significant bytes (`sigBytes`) in that array. It turns out that the encryption performed under the described conditions produces the *same* ciphertext in the word array as a plaintext explicitly padded with `0`-values or as the builtin Zero padding. However, the `0`-values used for encryption are not taken into account in `sigBytes` for the first case, whereas this happens for the last two cases:

```js
function encryptAndPrint(message, padding){
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(message, keyHex, {
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
        padding: padding
    });
    console.log("words: " + encrypted.ciphertext.words);
    console.log("sigBytes: " + encrypted.ciphertext.sigBytes); 
}

var keyHex = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('5401cae4-2c89-49');

// Implicit padding (not considered in sigBytes)
var message = 'Message';
encryptAndPrint(message, CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding);

// Explicit padding (considered in sigBytes)
var message = 'Message\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0';
encryptAndPrint(message, CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding);

// built-in Zero padding (considered in sigBytes)
var message = 'Message';
encryptAndPrint(message, CryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

However, during decryption *only* the significant bytes (more precise `ceil(sigBytes/4)` words) are taken into account, so that *effectively* a different ciphertext is decrypted than the original one. In the above example the ciphertext contained in the word array is `[1216989226, 1168217134, 91026943, 1588012560]`, but because of the not considered `0`-values in `sigBytes` `[1216989226, 1168217134, 0, 0]` is effectively decrypted, so that the decrypted plaintext does *not* match the original plaintext:

```js
function decryptAndPrint(ciphertext){
    var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
        {ciphertext: ciphertext}, 
        keyHex, 
        {mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB, padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding}
    );
    console.log("Decrypted (hex): " + decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex));
}

var keyHex = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('5401cae4-2c89-49');

// Decryption: The last two words are ignored 
var ciphertext = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create([1216989226, 1168217134, 91026943, 1588012560]);
ciphertext.sigBytes = 7; 
decryptAndPrint(ciphertext);

// Proof: The result is identical if the last two words are explicitly set to an arbitrary value, e.g. 0. 
var ciphertext = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create([1216989226, 1168217134, 0, 0]);
ciphertext.sigBytes = 7; 
decryptAndPrint(ciphertext);

// The correct result, if padding is considered in sigBytes
var ciphertext = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create([1216989226, 1168217134, 91026943, 1588012560]);
ciphertext.sigBytes = 16; 
decryptAndPrint(ciphertext);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

This is probably a bug in *CryptoJS*. For a block cipher with padding disabled, `sigBytes` should be an integer multiple of the blocksize (if no stream cipher mode is used). If this condition is not met, it should be handled as an error, e.g. with an exception. This applies to both, the plaintext for encryption and the ciphertext for decryption.

Comment: Thanks for your brief answer it helped me understand why my code was working when I switched to zero-padding. Regarding the purpose of such processing, I am currently working on a project where it is getting used.

Comment: @AbhinavBhardwaj - The comment concerning the purpose of such a processing referred to the CryptoJS implementation itself. I rephrased that.