# How can I prevent UTF8 strings from being allowed in my HTTP queries using JS (Node.js)?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, character-encoding

I have a MySQL table where the username field is a latin1 charset. If I search this table with a UTF8 string, I get this error:

```
Error: ER_CANT_AGGREGATE_2COLLATIONS: Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'like'
```

*Side question: is this because I'm using the LIKE statement, specifically?*

I feel like the only solution to my problem is to check if the username parameter from the HTTP query is a latin1 compatible string or not. If it is not, then omit it from the SQL query.

How could I check if a particular string is compatible with a specific character set like latin1 in JavaScript/Node.js?

Comment: Even swedes should be using UTF8

Comment: Also, you can use [iconv middleware](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-iconv) for Node to convert strings to different character encodings etc.

Comment: adeneo: I don't think UTF8 is a good idea for usernames https://labs.spotify.com/2013/06/18/creative-usernames/

Comment: And why would you think Latin1 is better, which only supports very few characters, when UFT-8 supports just about everyting -> [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708958/differences-between-utf8-and-latin1#answer-2709023)

Comment: There are issues I don't want to run into. Read the article about this from Spotify. I could try to solve the problems, but that's extra overhead I don't need. The simpler solution is to just restrict usernames to a subset of characters in latin1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized a good solution to my problem is to just convert the encodings within SQL using the CONVERT function.